# Are .NET MySqlTransactions batched/buffered locally?

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, database-performance, mysql-connector

Let's say you have a million rows to insert into a remote database.

As a no-brainer, you've done the following to improve performance:

1. Reusing a single MySQL connection
2. Creating a single prepared `MySqlCommand` which you'll reuse for all your inserts
3. Using `MySqlTransaction` to prevent autocommit after each and every insert and only calling `transaction.Commit()` when you're done with the batch.

The question is simple enough: does the MySQL Connector.NET automatically perform batching of transactions under these circumstances, or should you separately concatenate multiple rows into a single `INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES (..), (..), (..), (..), ...;` and execute multiple of these in your transaction?

At what point does it become a good idea to use `MySqlBulkLoader` instead?

Comment: I don't know this for a fact, but I don't think that this behavior exists in the MySql Connector because one would not expect it to be there. Although it makes sense, this is not what most of developers think of when doing multiple calls to command.ExecuteNonQuery. Good question, though!

Comment: @tucaz sound logic, fine reasoning. I'd have implemented it if I were the one writing the adapter, but that's just me. I know it's open source and I should probably just go download it and see for myself..... *grumble*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: no, they are not. Even when using compiled statements, each time you add a parameter, the data is sent over the wire, then more remote communication at the time of execution.